# Исчезновение текста

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать так, чтобы даже если человек не нажимал на текст, то он все равно бы исчез через одну минуту и переключился на другой текст (`anw2`)?

Код:

```js
function good() {
  var good = $('#anw').fadeOut(1);
  var good = $('#anw2').fadeIn(400);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 onclick="good()" id="anw">тыкни шо ле</h3>
<h3 id="anw2">Я РОДИЛСЯ!</h3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    $('#anw').delay( 6000 ).fadeOut(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 onclick="good()" id="anw">тыкни шо ле</h3>
<h3 id="anw2">Я РОДИЛСЯ!</h3>
```

delay - время задержки в миллисекундах, после загрузки страницы. Хотите минуту - ставьте 60000.